# How can I use global method in php mvc

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, helper

I'm trying to understand the structure of MVC but I've stumbled upon a place.
How I should integrate global functions which using all pages in that structure.

To give an example;

I have a method which needed for all pages, Im displaying this in sidebar.

```
public function user_credit( $userid ){
  return $this->db->getSingleRow( "SELECT * FROM user_credit WHERE userid = $userid" );
}
```

Some pages dont need model file. I dont want to create model for all pages and add this method to all.

My Solutions;

1 ) I created a globalFunc.php and I saved in helpers folder.

globalFunc.php

> // Extened model because I need db connection
>   class GlobalFunc extends Model {
>
> ```
> function __construct(){
>      parent::__construct();
> }
>   public function user_credit( $userid ){
>     return $this->db->getSingleRow( "SELECT * FROM user_credit WHERE userid = $userid" );}
> ```

and I add loadHelper Method in base controller.

2 ) I saved globalFunc.php in Models folder.
and I added loadCustomModel method in base Controller.

but this ways did not satisfy me. How should I follow a path?

Comment: "MVC" is **not an acronym for "my very code"**. MVC pattern defines the constraints for information flow between application layers. Whether you use function or not has **NO** relation to MVC pattern. Also, model is **NOT** a class or table abstraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, do some more Reading on the Concept of MVC first. You'll get there.

To your Question: For Resources that have to be used by several other Resources, Components etc. etc. you usually use a Service. In some cases a Helper is a good Solution as well.
Template Engines like Twig for Instance can use View Helpers for rendering. But those should be very abstract.

Services should be managed using [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection).
You could have a DI Container which then provides instances of the services needed and can be used to manipulate them.

The Symfony2 Framework has a good DI Container Component that you can use. They also have a good [Documentation Article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html) on the DI Concept I think.